# Transform list of arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I'm new to python. How is possible to transform an array like this:

```
x=[[0.3], [0.07], [0.06]]
```

into:

```
x=[0.3,0.07, 0.06]
```

?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following list comprehension may be useful.

```
>>> x=[[0.3], [0.07], [0.06]]
>>> y = [a for [a] in x]
>>> y
[0.3, 0.07, 0.06]
```

Considering that the inner values are of type `list` too.

A similar but more readable code, as given by [cdhowie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501250/cdhowie) is as follows.

```
>>> x=[[0.3], [0.07], [0.06]]
>>> y = [a[0] for a in x]
>>> y
[0.3, 0.07, 0.06]
```

Comment: Or `y = [a[0] for a in x]`, which is equivalent, assuming that the input elements are lists and not some other indexable object.

Comment: Yeah. That is an equivalent method too. You mind if I tag you and include that in the answer? Might be helpful for other people.

Comment: Not at all, go for it.

Comment: Thanks to all. All of your answers have been very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

This is a classic use of `itertools.chain.from_iterable`

```
from itertools import chain
print list(chain.from_iterable(x))
```

Where this example really shines is when you have an iterable with arbitrary length iterables inside it:

```
[[0],[12,15],[32,24,101],[42]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_x = []
for elem in x:
    new_x.extend(elem)
```

This works for any number of elements per sublist.

Comment: Tnx F3AR3DLEGEND, it works too!